# Magento - Displaying reward points on products with Tax

Tags: magento, discounts

We run a Magento Based e-commerce site. It is running Magento Enterprise 1.10.

We are in the UK - so we like to show all prices inclusive of Tax(VAT). Our store is set up with Prices entered inclusive of VAT, and Magento back-calculates the VAT at the checkout.

The site uses the built in enterprise Reward points functionality, and offers customers 10 points for every £1 they spend.

Displaying reward points (currently using the function "echo $this->getRewardPoints()" in the catalog and basket) shows the reward points inclusive of tax (so £15 = 150 points) but in the checkout, using the same function to show potential points for an item calculates the reward points on the item minus tax (so £15 = 120 points).

When the order is placed, the reward points are added to the customers account Minus the tax. This is obviously confusing for the users.

As a temporary measure I have stopped showing the incorrect points amount on the

**We are looking to either:**

**a)** Get Magento to always display points inclusive of VAT - and add the correct amount of points when an order is placed (and leave the points - pounds ratio as is)
**b)** Get Magento to always display and add points excluding VAT - and hence we would put the points - pounds ratio up to compensate.

Any help or pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a client that needed this too, so I wrote a custom module that overrides the function that calculates the rewards only on pre-tax, to allow it to calculate on price + tax too. I just added a new option to the rewards configuration area to allow calculation including tax yes or no.

Don't want to go through the process of describing how to create a custom module (there's plenty of resources for that), but the actual function that does the calculation is in this file:
    code/core/enterprise/reward/model/action/OrderExtra.php

If you want to do it quick and dirty, find the getPoints function and change the $monetaryAmount calculation to be (if there is a $quote):

```
$monetaryAmount = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() - $address->getBaseShippingAmount();
```

and (if no $quote)

```
$monetaryAmount = $this->getEntity()->getBaseTotalPaid() - $this->getEntity()->getBaseShippingAmount();
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: The actual code from the getPoints function should look something like this:

```
if ($this->_quote) {
        $quote = $this->_quote;
        // known issue: no support for multishipping quote
        $address = $quote->getIsVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
        // use only money customer spend - shipping & tax
        $monetaryAmount = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() - $address->getBaseShippingAmount();

        // *****CALCULATE POINTS INCLUDING TAX
        $monetaryAmount -= $address->getBaseTaxAmount();

        // set points to 0 if calcualtion is negative
        $monetaryAmount = $monetaryAmount < 0 ? 0 : $monetaryAmount;
    } else {
      // use only money customer spend - shipping
        $monetaryAmount = $this->getEntity()->getBaseTotalPaid() - $this->getEntity()->getBaseShippingAmount();

        // *****CALCULATE POINTS INCLUDING TAX
        $monetaryAmount -= $this->getEntity()->getBaseTaxAmount();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same problem, however found it to be simpler to just remove the shipping tax.

```
$monetaryAmount = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal()
- $address->getBaseShippingAmount()
- $address->getBaseShippingTaxAmount();
```

and changes to the else function. Works perfectly

```
$monetaryAmount = $this->getEntity()->getBaseTotalPaid()
- $this->getEntity()->getBaseShippingAmount()
- $this->getEntity()->getBaseShippingTaxAmount();
```